# Calculate a team's lead at regular intervals based on scoring data

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a set of scoring data from a bunch of hockey games and I'm stuck at a stage of my analysis. I'm trying to plot the home team's lead for every ten minutes of every game.

Here's an example of where I've gotten my dataset so far:

```
library(tidyverse)

# Generate example data ordered by gameid and event_ts
game <- tibble(event_type = "goal", event_ts = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 60),
       team = sample(c("home", "away"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.55,0.45)),
       gameid = sample(100:300, size = 1000, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(gameid, event_ts)
```

I know that I can get the final score of each game using `summarise`. Here's a quick example that assumes both teams score at least one goal in every game:

```
game %>%
  group_by(gameid, team) %>%
  summarise(goals = n()) %>%
  spread(key = team, value = goals) %>%
  mutate(away = ifelse(is.null(away), 0, away))
```

I'd like to figure out the home team's lead (positive or negative) at ten minute intervals throughout the game. That requires summing all scoring that has happened up to that point. Here's an example of the structure I'd like to get:

```
finished_demo <- tibble(
  gameid = sort(rep_len(seq(100, 300, 1), 1206)),
  timestamp = rep(seq(10, 60, 10), 201),
  home_lead = round(runif(
    n = 1206, min = -5, max = 7
  ))
) %>% arrange(gameid, timestamp)
```

Comment: `library(tidyverse); game %>% mutate(event_ts = ceiling(event_ts / 10) * 10) %>% complete(event_ts, gameid, team) %>% group_by(gameid, team, event_ts) %>% summarise(score = coalesce(sum(event_type == 'goal'), 0L)) %>% summarise(ts = list(event_ts), score = list(cumsum(score))) %>% unnest() %>% spread(team, score) %>% mutate(home_lead = home - away)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here's one way of accomplishing it using *data.table*, IIUC:

```
require(data.table)
setDT(game) # generated with op's code but with a seed(1L)

key <- CJ(gameid=unique(game$gameid), start=1L, end=(1:6)*10L)
ans <- game[key, on=.(gameid, event_ts >= start, event_ts <= end),  # (1)
              .(home_lead=sum(team == "home")-sum(team == "away")), # (2)
              by=.EACHI]                                            # (3)

head(ans)
#    gameid event_ts event_ts home_lead
# 1:    100        1       10        NA
# 2:    100        1       20         1
# 3:    100        1       30         0
# 4:    100        1       40         0
# 5:    100        1       50        -1
# 6:    100        1       60        -2
```

You can rename the duplicate column names (I'll fix this when I get time to work on it).

---

(1) searches for row indices in `game` that matches for every row in `key` while matching on the conditions provided under `on` argument.

(2) computes the lead of `home` team.

(3) `.EACHI` informs that the home team lead should be computed on matching rows of `game` for every row of `key`.

`NA` implies there were no matching events.. if necessary they can be replaced to `0` by doing:

```
ans[is.na(home_lead), home_lead := 0L]
```

Answer (score 1):

How about this?

```
game %>% 
mutate(ten_min = event_ts %/% 10,
       homegoal = if_else(team == 'home', 1, -1)) %>% 
group_by(ten_min, gameid) %>% 
summarize(home_lead_interval = sum(homegoal)) %>% 
ungroup() %>% 
group_by(gameid) %>% 
mutate(home_lead = cumsum(home_lead_interval)) %>% 
arrange(gameid, ten_min)
# Source: local data frame [683 x 4]
# Groups: gameid [198]
# 
#    ten_min gameid home_lead_interval home_lead
#      <dbl>  <int>              <dbl>     <dbl>
# 1        0    100                  0         0
# 2        1    100                 -1        -1
# 3        2    100                 -3        -4
# 4        3    100                 -1        -5
# 5        4    100                  2        -3
# 6        5    100                 -1        -4
# 7        1    101                  1         1
# 8        2    101                  1         2
# 9        4    101                 -2         0
# 10       0    102                  1         1
# # ... with 673 more rows
```

Answer (score 1):

I'm like 99% sure someone can rewrite this with some that embedded/nested (?) structure found in purrr.  Different `nrow()` from results above (with same data) so no guarantee solution is right.

```
game %>%
      group_by(gameid) %>%
      do(data.frame(time = 10 * (1:(max(.$event_ts) %/% 10)))) %>%
      apply(1, function(x) {
                            g = x[1] %>% unlist
                            t = x[2] %>% unlist
                            game %>%
                              filter(gameid == g, event_ts < t) %>%
                              group_by(gameid, team) %>%
                              summarise(goals = n()) %>%
                              mutate(time = t)
                           }) %>%
      bind_rows %>%
      spread(key = team, value = goals) %>%
      mutate_all(as.numeric) %>%
      mutate(away = ifelse(is.na(away), 0, away),
             home = ifelse(is.na(home), 0, home))


   gameid  time  away  home
    <int> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>
1     100    10     0     1
2     100    20     1     3
3     100    30     1     3
4     101    20     0     1
5     101    30     1     1
6     101    40     1     2
7     101    50     1     2
```

Answer (score 1):

My idea is to get the score of home and away for each 10 minutes. Then you can group the `data.frame` based on gameid and create the result you want.

```
set.seed(123)
# Generate example data ordered by gameid and event_ts
game <- tibble(event_type = "goal", event_ts = runif(n = 1000, min = 0, max = 60),
               team = sample(c("home", "away"), size = 1000, replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.55,0.45)),
               gameid = sample(100:300, size = 1000, replace = TRUE)) %>%
  arrange(gameid, event_ts)

# Change the event_ts and get all 10 minutes intervals
hl <- game %>%
  mutate(event_ts=ceiling(event_ts / 10) * 10) %>%
  dcast(gameid + event_ts ~ team, length) %>%
  right_join(expand.grid(gameid=unique(game$gameid), event_ts=seq(10, 60, 10)))
hl$away[is.na(hl$away)] <- 0
hl$home[is.na(hl$home)] <- 0
# Get the home lead
hl <- hl %>%
  arrange(gameid, event_ts) %>%
  group_by(gameid) %>%
  mutate(away=cumsum(away),
         home=cumsum(home),
         home_lead=home - away)

# Check the game 100 and 101
game %>% filter(gameid %in% 100:101)
# A tibble: 7 × 4
  event_type  event_ts  team gameid
       <chr>     <dbl> <chr>  <int>
1       goal 30.460972  home    100
2       goal 57.270219  home    100
3       goal  1.126093  home    101
4       goal 27.879957  home    101
5       goal 33.086101  home    101
6       goal 42.497419  away    101
7       goal 45.649418  home    101

hl %>% filter(gameid %in% 100:101)
Source: local data frame [12 x 5]
Groups: gameid [2]

   gameid event_ts  away  home home_lead
    <int>    <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>     <dbl>
1     100       10     0     0         0
2     100       20     0     0         0
3     100       30     0     0         0
4     100       40     0     1         1
5     100       50     0     1         1
6     100       60     0     2         2
7     101       10     0     1         1
8     101       20     0     1         1
9     101       30     0     2         2
10    101       40     0     3         3
11    101       50     1     4         3
12    101       60     1     4         3
```